# How to set 1 timepicker in 2 different EditText?

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-layout

I have 2 edit text fields one for starting time and one for ending time. And I have written
a single java function for time picker for both of the edit text fields.

The issue is when I try to set time in the ending time edit text field it sets time to the starting time
edit text field.

This my xml code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/starting_time_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:hint="Click To Add Starting Time Of Course"
        android:textStyle="bold">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/ending_time_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="355dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:hint="Click To Add Ending Time Of Course"
        android:textStyle="bold">
```

This is my java code for time picker:

```
    Button backButton;
    EditText startingTime;
    EditText endingTime;
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
    Calendar calender;
    int currentHour;
    int currentMinute;
    String amPm;
    String minuteWith_0_OnLeft;

    startingTime = findViewById(R.id.starting_time_et);
    startingTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startingTimeAndEndingTime();
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        endingTime = findViewById(R.id.ending_time_et);

        endingTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startingTimeAndEndingTime();
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });


        public void startingTimeAndEndingTime(){
        calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentHour = calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        currentMinute = calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AddCourses.this, new 
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute){
                if(hourOfDay > 12)
                {
                    hourOfDay -= 12;
                    amPm = "Pm";
                }
                else if(hourOfDay == 0)
                {
                    hourOfDay += 12;
                    amPm = "Am";
                }
                else if(hourOfDay == 12)
                {
                    amPm = "Pm";
                }
                else
                {
                    amPm = "AM";
                }

                if( minute < 10 )
                {
                    minuteWith_0_OnLeft = "0" + minute;
                }
                else
                {
                    minuteWith_0_OnLeft = String.valueOf(minute);
                }

                startingTime.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}{2}", hourOfDay, minuteWith_0_OnLeft, amPm));

            }
        }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is working as expected. You are setting the text of the `startingTime` EditText in `startingTimeAndEndingTime()` function and calling it from both `startingTime` and `endingTime` click listener. To fix this you can modify your your `startingTimeAndEndingTime()` function like this.

```
public void startingTimeAndEndingTime(boolean isStart) {
calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentHour = calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    currentMinute = calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AddCourses.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute)
        {

            if(hourOfDay > 12)
            {

                hourOfDay -= 12;
                amPm = "Pm";

            }
            else if(hourOfDay == 0)
            {

                hourOfDay += 12;
                amPm = "Am";

            }
            else if(hourOfDay == 12)
            {

                amPm = "Pm";

            }
            else
            {

                amPm = "AM";

            }

            if( minute < 10 )
            {

                minuteWith_0_OnLeft = "0" + minute;

            }
            else
            {

                minuteWith_0_OnLeft = String.valueOf(minute);

            }

if (isStart) {
            startingTime.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}{2}", hourOfDay, minuteWith_0_OnLeft, amPm));
} else {
            endingTime.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}{2}", hourOfDay, minuteWith_0_OnLeft, amPm));
}

        }
    }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);

}
```

Comment: I don't know what and how to pass in a boolean variable when I call this function but your above solution gave me an idea. Thanks for your suggestion and reply.

Answer (score 0):

Let my startingTimeAndEndingTime Function accept an EditText parameter like this:
public void startingTimeAndEndingTime(EditText editText)

And then inside that method, replace startingTime.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}{2}", hourOfDay, minuteWith_0_OnLeft, amPm)); with this:
editText.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}{2}", hourOfDay, minuteWith_0_OnLeft, amPm));

Now in onClick of startingTime and endingTime, call the method like this, for startingTime:
startingTimeAndEndingTime(startingTime);

and for endingTime:
startingTimeAndEndingTime(endingTime);

SO my code will be like this:

startingTime = findViewById(R.id.starting_time_et);

```
    startingTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            startingTimeAndEndingTime( startingTime );

            timePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });

    endingTime = findViewById(R.id.ending_time_et);

    endingTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            startingTimeAndEndingTime( endingTime );

            timePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });
```

public void startingTimeAndEndingTime( EditText startingAndEndingTImeEt )
{

```
    calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentHour = calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    currentMinute = calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AddCourses.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute)
        {

            if(hourOfDay > 12)
            {

                hourOfDay -= 12;
                amPm = "Pm";

            }
            else if(hourOfDay == 0)
            {

                hourOfDay += 12;
                amPm = "Am";

            }
            else if(hourOfDay == 12)
            {

                amPm = "Pm";

            }
            else
            {

                amPm = "AM";

            }

            if( minute < 10 )
            {

                minuteWith_0_OnLeft = "0" + minute;

            }
            else
            {

                minuteWith_0_OnLeft = String.valueOf(minute);

            }

            //startingTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute + amPm);

            startingAndEndingTImeEt.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}{2}", hourOfDay, minuteWith_0_OnLeft, amPm));

        }

    }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);
```

}